# Application of derivatives. Differentiation w.r.t. constant.

Tags: derivatives

For this question :

A cylindrical container is to be made from certain solid material with the following constraints: It has
fixed inner volume of V mm3
, has a 2 mm thick solid wall and is open at the top. The bottom of the
container is solid circular disc of thickness 2 mm and is of radius equal to the outer radius of the
container.
If the volume of the material used to make the container is minimum when the inner radius of the
container is 10 mm, then the value of 250/V is ?

Solution says that you first have to find the volume of material as a function of inner radius and then differentiate it w.r.t. r. But I am confused that if r = constant then how can we differentiate the function w.r.t. r ?

Please help.

Comment: $r$ is not a constant actually. You are **varying** $r$ to find minimum volume of material.

Comment: But it is given in the question that r=10

Comment: $r$ when volume of material is minimum is $10$ but in fact $r$ is still a variable. It does **not** have to be $10$ but when $r=10$ the material used just happens to be minimum.

Comment: OK thanks.. I got it.. I missed the word `when`.   /-is minimum WHEN the inner radius of the container is 10 mm. -/